# How to convert html entities to utf-8 when upload to database? PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I upload a symbol '<' to database getting the symbol from a `<div value = '<'>`.
And when I watch the database result, there displayed a html entity `&lt;`. And I tried `html_entity_decode()`, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code div:

```
<option value = "<"   <?php if ( ! empty ( $dwwp_stored_meta['operator-post'] ) ) {
if ( $dwwp_stored_meta['operator-post'][0]== '<' )
    echo 'selected = "selected"';
} ?>> < </option>
```

And here is the update function:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'operator', sanitize_text_field(html_entity_decode($_POST[ 'operator' ],ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8" )));
```

But the function upload a html  entity, how can I solve it? thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sanitize_text_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) says: "Converts single < characters to entities"

So, just don't use that function. It has nothing to do with SQL anyway - it is meant for outputting to a HTML text field, not for SQL text fields.

Comment: Solved Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use built in PHP utf8-encode function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php